# data visualisation - which kind of chart that comfortable with time and multiple data columns?

Tags: python, excel, charts

I have an excel file which consists of the 4 spreadsheets for representing the period of time. each spreadsheet has 3 columns data which are 'subject', 'measure', and 'frequency' (the data is considering the student's interested rate in every 10 years)

E.G, sheet 1970-1980

```
          frequency   score
math         3.4        1
english      2.5       0.95
art          0.4       0.8
```

sheet 1981-1990

```
          frequency   score
math         4.7       0.5
english      2.3       0.48
art          -0.4      0.13
```

sheet 1991-2000

```
          frequency   score
math         4.2       0.6
english      2.1       0.77
art          -0.2      0.24
```

sheet 2000-2010

```
          frequency   score
math         4.5       0.55
english      1.9       0.66
art          -0.23      0.19
```

I have created the scatter plot for each period of time, but I would like to see the movement of the data over the period of time. for example, an x-axis represents the time period and a y-axis represents the frequency and score.

are any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I will reproduce the tables that you have here as pandas Dataframes and for three decades:

```
data_80s = {'math':[ 3.4, 1], 'english':[2.5, 0.95],'art':[0.4, 0.8]}
df_80s = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_80s, orient = 'index', columns=['frequency', 
'score'])
df_80s['decade'] = pd.to_datetime(1990, format='%Y')
df_80s['index'] = df_80s.index

data_90s = {'math':[ 4.7, 0.5], 'english':[2.3, 0.48],'art':[-0.4, 0.13]}
df_90s = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_90s, orient = 'index', columns=['frequency', 
'score'])
df_90s['decade'] = pd.to_datetime(1990, format='%Y')
df_90s['index'] = df_90s.index
data_20s = {'math':[ 4.2, 0.6], 'english':[2.1, 0.77],'art':[-0.2, 0.24]}
df_20s = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_20s, orient = 'index', columns=['frequency', 
'score'])
 df_20s['decade'] = pd.to_datetime(2000, format='%Y')
 df_20s['index'] = df_20s.index
```

Probably you will just need to convert your excell sheet to pandas Dataframes. Just don't forget to add the extra column `index` and `decade`.

Then you can merge the dataframes:

`frames = [df_90s, df_20s]
 result = df_80s.append(frames)`

And finally plot whatever you want:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(15,10))
 sns.lineplot(x='decade', y='score',  hue = 'index', data=result, ax=ax1)
 sns.lineplot(x='decade', y='frequency', hue = 'index', data=result, ax=ax2)
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i just have time to try your comment. i have found this error and not sure which library that will be used for this. but i already import the seaborn T T -> AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'lineplot'

Comment: Probably you have a version of `seaborn` that does not support the function. Check the version by running `print(seaborn.__version__)`.  If it's not the 0.9.0, then upgrade it.

Comment: it's working now, thank you for your suggestion, i will try to adapt with my real data ^^